# while tesing, I got erlang_error: "{badmatch,{error,system_limit}},{module,function,3}"?

Tags: erlang, network-programming

I am doing load testing of my server with number of clients(200, 300, 500, ....3000). For testing I am using windows 64 bit systems and I am running server on one system and clients on another system. All the clients can do connections successfully, but after  one minute or two minutes later, server through an erlang:error -> **"{badmatch,{error,system_limit}},{module,accept_function,3}"** for some server instances and dies those server instances. Can any on have a solution for this ?

Thank you in advance..

sreenivas, India.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you have hit the system limit on the number of ports you are allowed to open on your system. Have a read of [this doc here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html#id2265856) to see if you can determine what your limits are.

In particular:

> **Open ports** The maximum number of
>   simultaneously open Erlang ports is by
>   default 1024. This limit can be raised
>   up to at most 268435456 at startup
>   (see environment variable
>   ERL_MAX_PORTS in erlang(3)) The
>   maximum limit of 268435456 open ports
>   will at least on a 32-bit architecture
>   be impossible to reach due to memory
>   shortage.
>
> **Open files, and sockets** The maximum
>   number of simultaneously open files
>   and sockets depend on the maximum
>   number of Erlang ports available, and
>   operating system specific settings and
>   limits.