# Erlang file:consult and system_limit error

Tags: file, io, erlang, limit

I use file:consult function to read data from config file of my application. But some times i got error: **{badmatch,{error,system_limit}}** How can i avoid this?

I read about ERL_MAX_PORTS, but i haven't this variable:

```
echo $ERL_MAX_PORTS
```

i got empty string. How i can correctly set ERL_MAX_PORTS or can i find other methods to avoid this error?

Thank you

Comment: Probably dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4242887/298282

Comment: Actually it's not clear if the problem is max ports. It could be for example some atoms in config file with length > 255.

Comment: no, there isn't atoms with length > 255

Comment: Also, you may want to go back and get grips with why you suddenly are hitting limits. Is there another part of the system that works heavily with files? Are files leaking?

Comment: Can we see the configuration file?