# How do you set Erlang Environment Variables, specifically ERL_MAX_PORTS, in Windows?

Tags: windows, erlang, cmd, environment-variables

I have a problem with an Erlang program where I have reached the maximum number of open files. I have seen [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242887/while-tesing-i-got-erlang-error-badmatch-error-system-limit-module-funct) that this maximum can be increased using the environment variable `ERL_MAX_PORTS`. However, I am struggling to figure out how to do this.

When I type `set` in `cmd` I do not see any Erlang related Environment Variables, should I?

How do I set `ERL_MAX_PORTS`? From the Erlang shell or OS Shell?

Note. I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add ERL_MAX_PORTS to the arguments passed to the Erlang VM by launching it with `erl -env ERL_MAX_PORTS X` where X is the desired number of ports.

Comment: From [doc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) This environment variable is deprecated, and scheduled for removal in OTP-R17, but can still be used. +Q Number is preferable